# Problems when insert double value in MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, transactions, odbc

I get an error when I try to insert a double value into a table in MySQL. 
I use C# to build my transactions, and ODBC drivers to connect my database to my project.

In my aspx page I make a form which permit to the user to fill severals fields and submit the values. By an Ajax call, I go in my code behind sending the form's values. And i begin my transaction.

- If the user puts for instance "15.00" in the form for the double
  values, the resquest is Ok and there is not problems.
- But if he puts "15.65" I get an error which says that the column
  count of my table doesn't match with the request column count.

However, I check the double value and it is correct. I also try to put simple quotes next to the double value, but it doesn't work.

Here is the error :

```
`{"Message":"[MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.1.73-community]Column count doesn\u0027t match value count
 at row 1","StackTrace":"   à ADODB.ConnectionClass.Execute(String CommandText, Object& RecordsAffected
, Int32 Options)\r\n...
```

Here is my resquest :

```
Utils.ocn.Execute("INSERT INTO datas VALUES(0,null,null,null,null,null," + RecepAccId + ",1," + CafId + ",123,null,null," + NbrKilos + ",'" + ConvertedDate + "','" + Chrono + "','" + ConvertedTimeStamp + "','" + ChronoNum + "')", out x, -1);
```

The severals variables provening my function's parameters

There are 17 fields in my table and I send normally 17 values in my resquests. But when I set the double with numbers after the comma, I get a bug. And according to the error message, we can suppose that, the numbers after the comma are considerated like a other field in the insert !

In doubt I put the 17 fields'names after the table name in my resquest, but I get the same result.

Have you an idea to fix it ?

Comment: I think the value "15,00" is translated to two parameters - "15" and "00" in your INSERT statement, since you're doing simple concatenation (which is soooo wrong). Value "15.65" is just one value and so you're missing one additional param - you get only 16 instead of 17 as in previous case.

Comment: You have bigger problems than this error. I suggest you revise your code to prevent SQL injection first.

Comment: @MarkoJuvančič , i write an error the value is "15.00" and not with a ','. 15.00 Is considerated like only one value, because it works in this case. But I thing that '15.65' can be considerated like two distinct values. So  I get 18 fields, I think

Comment: @AndréKops , can you give me some tips why my SQL injection is wrong ?

Comment: Decimal point is never a parameter separator in SQL. Since you think you're writing "15.00", there are only two options: either you write "15" and "00" or "15.65" gets converted to empty string.

Comment: The way you generate your query leaves it open for any user to put malicious code in there. For instance the could type ;DROP DATABASE XXX in the field and delete your db (they'd actually need to do a little bit more, this is just a sample). You should do a google search for "SQL Injection", It's a well known hacking technique.

Comment: @AndréKops Thanks for the advise, I'll look to that problems.

Comment: I get the error, the double value in my function's parameter in translated with a comma in my string request, so i get 18 fields and it can't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your database driver to treat the values from the user input as individual pieces of data, you should use a parametrised query. So if your table had a single double column called, height for example.

```
INSERT INTO datas height
VALUES @height
```

Where `@height` is a double value parsed from the input from the request eg using `double parsedHeight = double.Parse(subbmittedValue)`. You can then add the parameter when making your SQL command by adding:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@height", parsedHeight);
```

As @Marko Juvančič says, using string concatenation from user input to create a sql statement is dangerous. In fact, it is a major security issue leaving you open to SQL injection. Imagine a malicious user entered a SQL query to delete datas in the form. Parametrising your query as described protects you from this by preventing the user from interfering with your query.

So putting all this together, instead of executing your concatenated statement with Utils.ocn.Execute use something like:

```
double parsedValue = double.Parse(valueFromRequest);
//be careful, this will throw if the user didn't enter a valid double.
string connectionString = yourConnectionString;
using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(
        "INSERT INTO datas columnName VALUES(@value)", connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", parsedValue);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: I fixed my problem just by replacing "," with "." in the double. Don't worry, the user can only put a double value, else he gets a error message that says him the entry is wrong. I also disable letters entry in this field.

Answer (score 0):

```
   private double failingGrade;
    public double getFailingGrade()
    {
        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(DBConnection.Connection()))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (MySqlCommand comm = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                comm.CommandText = "select failing from gradespercentage_tab";
               return failingGrade = double.Parse(comm.ExecuteScalar().ToString());

            }
        }
    }
```